# What type of data should be passed to domain events?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, and I'm still not clear on the correct approach. I've seen many examples online, but each one does it differently. The options I see are:

- Pass only primitive values
- Pass the complete model
- Pass new instances of value objects that refer to changes in the domain/model
- Create a specific DTO/object for each event with the data.

This is what I am currently doing, but it doesn't convince me. The example is in PHP, but I think it's perfectly understandable.

MyModel.php

```
    class MyModel {
    
         //...
         private MediaId $id;
         private Thumbnails $thumbnails;
         private File $file; 
         //...
    
        public function delete(): void
        {
            $this->record(
                new MediaDeleted(
                    $this->id->asString(),
                    [
                        'name' => $this->file->name(),
                        'thumbnails' => $this->thumbnails->toArray(),
                    ]
                )
            );
        }
}
```

MediaDeleted.php

```
final class MediaDeleted extends AbstractDomainEvent
{
    public function name(): string
    {
        return $this->payload()['name'];
    }

    /**
     * @return array<ThumbnailArray>
     */
    public function thumbnails(): array
    {
        return $this->payload()['thumbnails'];
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am passing the ID as a string, the filename as a string, and an array of the Thumbnail value object's properties to the `MediaDeleted` event.

How do you see it? What type of data is preferable to pass to domain events?

## Updated

The answer of @pgorecki has convinced me, so I will put an example to confirm if this way is correct, in order not to change too much.
It would now look like this.

```
public function delete(): void
{
    $this->record(
        new MediaDeleted(
            $this->id,
            new MediaDeletedEventPayload($this->file->copy(), $this->thumbnail->copy())
        )
    );
}
```

I'll explain a bit:

The ID of the aggregate is still outside the DTO, because `MediaDeleted` extends an abstract class that needs the ID parameter, so now the only thing I'm changing is the `$payload array` for the `MediaDeletedEventPayload` DTO, to this DTO I'm passing a copy of the value objects related to the change in the domain, in this way I'm passing objects in a reliable way and not having strange behaviours if I pass the same instance.

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A domain event is simply a data-holding structure or class (DTO), with all the information related to what just happened in the domain, and no logic. So I'd say *Create a specific DTO/object for each event with the data.* is the best choice. Why don't you start with the *less is more* approach? - think about the consumers of the event, and what data might they need.

Also, being able to serialize and deserialize the event objects is a good practice, since you could want to send them via a message broker (although this relates more to integration events than domain events).

Comment: Thank you very much you have convinced me, I have made an update and I would like you to check it to confirm and give you the correct answer.

Comment: Also, even if I pass a DTO instead of primitive values, converting this data either to JSON/serialized for future sending to RabbitMQ, I don't think it's a problem, I can always do it where the sending is done, right? I'm saying this because I haven't gotten to the part where I need to send it to a work queue yet.